# Home wifi network not searching web using Ubuntu

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04

Problem:  Lost my wifi connection after using HP Laptop running uBuntu 18.04 in a public place.  My wifi symbol was gone when I got home.  When I click on System Task Bar it says wifi is not connected.  I then click on connect wifi, and then choose my home network and it asks for authentication.  My wifi signal then appears and Ubuntu shows that I am connected to my network.  I am using Firefox as my web browser..  When I try to go anywhere on the web I get a "Hmmm we can't find that website" no matter what it is.  I have another laptop, a DELL Latitude running Win 7 and it connects to my home network with no problem.   Also, now when I return to this restaurant with either laptop it connects to their wifi with no problem.

Did I get hacked at the public wifi?  What do I have to do to get my wifi working again?  Anyone have any suggestions?  Is this a Mozilla problem as I use that on both laptops but the one running Ubuntu is giving problem.

Comment: What does `nslookup askubuntu.com` tell you about nameserver that it's using ? If you suspended the laptop after using the laptop after using it on public wifi it is quite possible that it is still using the old nameserver to resolve websites ( i.e., find what IP address belongs to a website )

Comment: Try the same command `nslookup` in your other Windows 7 laptop and compare the nameservers that the two machines are using

Answer (score 0):

My idea is that there is kind of proxy installed. Things to be checked are Wi-Fi and Network in Settings. On the other hand, contrary to other browsers, Firefox may use its own Connection Settings (in preferences - Network Settings). There are 4 possible choices: No proxy, Auto-detect, system proxy and manual proxy. At last, and it worked for me, you can remove firewall in terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) with sudo ufw disable.